# Is it possible to build and run Go plugins for Linux/ARM?

Tags: linux, go, plugins, arm

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm` does not work for plugins? Plugins do not run on linux/arm ? I have built a simple example, that builds a simple plugin like:
`CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build -ldflags="-pluginpath=blah" -buildmode=plugin -o ./arm-dist/reader.linux.arm.so /app/plugins/reader/...`

No errors,

however when a main app on a raspberrypi tries to open the plugin, it says: `could not open ./arm-dist/caller.linux.arm.so plugin: not implemented`

is this the case? or did I miss something? somewhat of a showstopper...

**Update:**

`CGO_ENABLED=1` was missing for the main app, d'oh!
Now I am stuck at a different error message

`could not open /home/pi/plugged/reader.linux.arm.so plugin.Open("/home/pi/plugged/reader.linux.arm.so"): /home/pi/plugged/reader.linux.arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: So what part of "No such file or directory" are you having trouble with?

Comment: The file is there. "/home/pi/plugged/reader.linux.arm.so" 
`file /home/pi/plugged/reader.linux.arm.so 
/home/pi/plugged/reader.linux.arm.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=d7a779de89f48ffb77de2424a5d36e69187124c7, not stripped`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else struggling with this, the problem was the build process itself. This is what worked:

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 go build -ldflags="-pluginpath=blah -extld=$CC" -buildmode=plugin -o ./arm-dist/reader.linux.arm.so /app/plugins/reader/...
```

I used a different compiler and set `-extld=$CC` ldflag.